# IF function with 3 conditions and 3 outcomes for text

Tags: excel

I need to create a function as below:
If cell is blank then blank.
If cell is not blank and no "A" then 8.
If cell is "A" then 6

It seems that this is bit more complicated than I anticipated. Helps are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nested IF:

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(A1="A",6,8))
```

Comment: Wow, it's that simple and I was looking at If(NOT(OR( and stuff haha. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer when the question is 15 minutes old.